# How to render a dropdown menu inside a list in Ant Design v5?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design for the first time, learning as I go along. I'm getting the overlay being deprecated warning in the console and can't figure out how to solve it. As currently written, using overlay when rendering a dropdown inside a list, the code works as expected.

A list of categories is rendered from the backend and the user can either delete or edit a category.

I appreciate your assistance.

```
import { Divider, List, Dropdown, Menu, Modal, Input } from "antd"
import axios from "axios"
import Spinner from "../../Components/Spinner/index"
import "./index.css"

export default function ViewCategories() {
  const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [selectedCategoryId, setSelectedCategoryId] = useState(null)
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const [newCategoryName, setNewCategoryName] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios.get("http://localhost:5555/categories")
      .then((response) => {
        setCategoryList(response.data.data)
        // setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        // setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  const handleEdit = (newCategoryName) => {
    // Update category name in the backend and then update the category list
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:5555/categories/${selectedCategoryId}`, { 
        name: newCategoryName
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const updatedList = categoryList.map((category) => {
          if (category._id === selectedCategoryId) {
            return { ...category, name: newCategoryName }
          }
          return category
        })
        setCategoryList(updatedList)
        setIsModalOpen(false)
        setNewCategoryName("")
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  const handleDelete = () => {
    // Delete category from the backend and then update the category list
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5555/categories/${selectedCategoryId}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const updatedList = categoryList.filter(
          (category) => category._id !== selectedCategoryId
        )
        setCategoryList(updatedList)
        setSelectedCategoryId(null)
        setIsModalOpen(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  const menu = (
    <Menu onClick={({ key }) => handleMenuClick(key)}>
      <Menu.Item key="edit">Edit</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="delete">Delete</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  )

  const handleMenuClick = (key) => {
    if (key === 'edit') {
      setIsModalOpen(true);
    } else if (key === 'delete') {
      handleDelete();
    }
  }

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    setNewCategoryName(null)
  }

  return (
    <div className="categoryList">
      <Divider orientation="left">Categories</Divider>
      <List
        size="large"
        bordered
        dataSource={categoryList}
        renderItem={(category) => (
          <List.Item key={category.id}>
            <Dropdown
              overlay={menu}
              trigger={["click"]}
              onOpenChange={(open) =>
                open && setSelectedCategoryId(category._id)
              }
            >
              <span>{category.name}</span>
            </Dropdown>
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
        <Modal
          title="Edit Category"
          open={isModalOpen}
          onOk={() => handleEdit(newCategoryName)}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
        >
          <Input
            value={newCategoryName}
            onChange={(e) => setNewCategoryName(e.target.value)}
            onPressEnter={() => handleEdit(newCategoryName)}
          />
        </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```